# Why does my button disappear? (trying to understand the basics)

Tags: javascript

I have to note that i'm fairly new to writing code. I've been trying to write some code to learn the basics. Anyway the problem i have is that the button in the code beneath disappears whenever i call it's function (click it). Is there any way that i can change this so that i can keep pressing the button and adding 1 to the number?

I would appreciate it very much if someone can help me out here.

```
<title>testingstuff</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">

var givenNumber = parseFloat(prompt("Give a number to start with"))
document.write (givenNumber)

function addingFunc()
{
    document.write(givenNumber+1)
};
```

```
<button onclick=addingFunc();>Click here for +1</button>
```

Comment: You for got quotes - `onclick="addingFunc()"`

Answer (score 4):

`document.write` overwrites the entire document when it's called after the document has finished loading, you can use `innerHTML` or any other method that appends content to the DOM instead :

```
function addingFunc() {
    document.getElementById('element_to_write_to').innerHTML = ++givenNumber;
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4dG2/)

Comment: Thnx alot for replying. Could you explain a little bit more about this "element"?

Comment: You create an element, as in any kind of element, give it an ID, and then use that ID in `getElementById` to add the content to that element.

Comment: Oh yea i see. Your "fiddle" is indeed exactly what i want. Let's see if i can understand this.

Comment: Can i ask you one more thing? i'd like to write out the number you gave as input in the "prompt" thing. How do i do that? If i use something like: 
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = givenNumber;
in a new function that i just call below that line of code it does not work... why?

Comment: Look at the fiddle, it works there because the script tag is added after the elements in the DOM, if you place the script in the head section of the page, the elements aren't available yet, and you can't set the innerHTML of something that isn't available..

Answer (score 0):

the problem is using:

```
document.write
```

whenever you do it it overrides all the html in the page.
add a div to your page, like this:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

then use this instead:

```
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = givenNumber+1;
```

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that. But why exactly? And what should i use instead document.write?

Comment: Thnx, let me check if i can understand it. 1 sec =]

Comment: So, first of all; this div thing should go into the body right? And yes this does let me keep the button but it doesn't let me use the button (to add 1) more than once.. It also just writes the number+1 on the next line. Maybe i'm using it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for

```
document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = givenNumber+1;
```